# Show list with radio button selection only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on a module where admin gets a list of candidates who have requested for approval. Currently I am using radio buttons for three selections and a submit button . Now I want to implement this only by selecting a radio button for the result list to appear. How can I implement this to show the list for all three different selections on the same page. 
Here is what I have created,

```
<form  action=""  method="POST">

          <input type='radio'  name='users' value='unapproved' checked /> Unapproved Candidates &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type='radio'  name='users' value='approved' /> Approved Candidates &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type='radio' id='show' name='users' value='all'  /> All Candidates &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input type="submit" value="View Candidates" id="submit" class="btn btn-success"><br><br>
```

And my mysql queries,

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 AND status =0";



if(isset($_POST['users'])){

 $users=$_POST['users'];
}else{
    $users='';
}


switch ($users)

{

case "all":
  $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3";
break;

case "approved":
   $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 AND status =1";
break;

case "unapproved":
  $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 AND status =0";
break;

}
```

I found out this can be implemented by AJAX but unable to figure out the exact solution. Can I get some insights over this, will be very helpful to me and will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class on every radio button tag and use `click` event to check the clicks and state of radio buttons. All you have to do is -

```
// Selecting a class using jquery. It will return all the elements that have this class
$(".radioButton").click(function() {
    // Using `this`, JS can identify which element has been clicked with class radioButton

    // Here I'm checking whether it has been selected or not
    if(this).is(":checked") {
            // Here I'm fetching the value of selected radio button
            var category = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
            // Url of your PHP code
            url: "YOUR_URL.php",
            // Method of your Ajax request
            method: "POST",
            // Data in case of post request
            data: {
                'users': category 
            },
            success: function(result){
                console.log("Response:\n"+result);
            },
            error: function(er){
                console.log("Error\n"+er);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the time . But the AJAX request is the key hereand I am unsure of implementing it

Comment: The URL and data part comprises of what.

Comment: As the name suggests, `url` is your URL that you want to hit using  ajax request and `data` is the payload or data that you are sending with that ajax request to that url.

Comment: See, I have three conditions as you can see in my code above . Listing is done for approved candidates, unapproved candidates and all candidates. All these three has three different MySQL queries. Now on the page that I am requesting, how should I write the queries.Please check my question updated.

Comment: Simply use a parameter in query string to distinguish every candidate category or pass parameter in post body.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the `data` part. I am unable to figure out. Keeping the above scenario in mind.

Comment: Answer updated. In the data part, you are sending the post data that you need on your php end.

Comment: Thanks for this. Now as there are three conditions so how to implement all three conditions as you depicted for one case 'all'. DO I need to make three separate AJAX requests?

Comment: Now what this category has to do? I mean do we need to define this somewhere. How its gonna take 'category'.

Comment: Anand, category is basically a variable that stores the value of currently clicked radio box. So if you select 'All' radio box, the category will have its value. I hope you are aware with JS variables.

Comment: Nope, I am sorry but I am not aware of JS much. I am new to PHP and struggling on that now. I hope you understand. So, now how to proceed.

Comment: Anand if you are new to JS then Ajax is quite advanced thing for you. First have a basic understanding of JS, then learn about how client servers works, what is this GET, POST, query string means. But as per your question, let me explain you what I'm doing in the code. I'll edit the answer with specific comments.

Comment: Thanks for your effort on this. Yes you are right in your views. But I just wanted how to figure out that `data` part and rest I could handle. I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Happy to help Anand. If you find it helpful. Mark the answer.